# mysql community server vs mysql installer

Tags: mysql, windows

I recently thought of upgrading mysql in my system for a project when I found two parallelly available downloads for windows in mysql site. I cannot figure out the difference between mysql community and mysql installer.

MySQL community is available for both 32 and 64 bit windows (both above 300 MBs) while mysql installer is 267 MB for 32 bit while just 1.6 MB for 64 bit (which looks like web installer).

So what extras are there in community server (its size is bigger) as compared to installer and if I go for windows installer, shall I go for 32 or 64 bit. I need offline installer though.

My system specs:

Windows 8.1 x64 Professional 
 8GB RAM

Link for mysql installer:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

Link for mysql community server:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

PS: I did try a google search but cant find any good articles. I only found difference between community server and cluster.

Moreover, half of my batch mates were running community server while half of them mysql installer. Couldn't find much of the difference.

Answer (score 66):

Both will install into same final setup. the web-community is online installer, you need to download to connect to the online server and installations files come from online while the community installer is an offline installer with full features. web-installer (online, need internet connection to complete the installation), community-installer(offline, full).

Answer (score 11):

The difference between MySQL Community (mysql-8.0.18-winx64) and MySQL Installer (mysql-installer-community-8.0.18.0.msi) is that the MySQL Installer has

1. MySQL Server
2. MySQL Connectors
3. MySQL Workbench and sample models
4. MySQL for Excel
5. MySQL for Visual Studio,
   Etc..

And MySQL Community only includes the MySQL Server.
Hope this helps anyone who is still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is that MSI installer come with all mysql products (mysql server, mysql workbeanch, plugins, etc) and you have a wizar that guide you through install and it's check dependencys . That is the only diference i found using the MSI installer and the comunity edition.

It is more easy to use MSI installer if you don't know what products you have to install on your computer.

Be careful when you use the web installer, because you need that internet connection at your workplace  work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are:

- MySQL Community is for all Operating Systems including only the Server itself, whereas
- MySQL Installer (MSI installer) is for Windows only and includes Windows specify integrations like Excel, and Visual Studio integrations.

Answer (score 0):

mysql installer contains all in one including workbench
mysql community only contains mysql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).