# Difference between mysql-web-community and my-sql-community

Tags: mysql

When I download MySQL for 82x, 32 bit MSI installer for Windows it shows two options:

> mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.13.0.msi (16.3M )

and

> mysql-installer community-8.0.13.0.msi (313.8M)

what is the difference between these two?

Comment: Slightly different question, same answer: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999715)

Comment: It is a different question, it asks to explain the labels on the web site, the other question explains the other labels. Even if it happens to be the same meaning behind 2 sets of labels it still requires 2 different questions to be asked for each set of labels.

Answer (score 12):

If you have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-web-community file.
If you do NOT have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-community file.

Comment: From [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html]  :  
  
**Note**  
Unlike the standard MySQL Installer, the smaller web-community version does not bundle any MySQL applications, but downloads only the MySQL products you choose to install.